# Is there a mechanism that allow journalists to access politicians movement information in Costa Rica?

Tags: costa-rica

According to [this article](https://www.digi24.ro/stiri/actualitate/rise-project-elena-udrea-se-afla-in-costa-rica-din-7-februarie-879220) (Romanian), the journalists find out virtually immediately that an important Romanian politicians entered Costa Rica:

> Elena Udrea did not appear at a time when she was charged with
>   illegally funding the 2009 election campaign. Her lawyer later
>   confirmed that the former minister had left for Greece in Athens.
>   After a week, it appears that Elena Udrea is in Costa Rica.

The article shows a picture of what it appears to be an official document showing her entrance in Costa Rica.

As a side note, [she was eventually convicted](https://www.romania-insider.com/elena-udrea-internationally-wanted/) for corruption.

However, I am interested more in how could the journalists access official/personal information about someone entrance in Costa Rica.

**Question:** Is there a mechanism that allow journalists to access politicians movement information in Costa Rica?

Comment: What was the source of the information? If the first article was from a Romanian newspaper, it seems probable that they got the information from Romania (some acquaintance or even some bank employee giving information about access to her assets).

Comment: @SJuan76 - this is not clear. The image suggests a document from Costa Rica since it is written in Spanish. IMO, this sort of information should be public, that's why I am interested if there is a way for this to reach Romanian journalists (e.g. maybe RiseProject has privileged access to some information in all countries where it operates).

Comment: I looked on the Costa Rican government website [here](http://www.migracion.go.cr/servicios_linea/index.html) and it seems you only need the identification number and date of birth to request this document. It looks like you're supposed to be the passport holder to request this but I don't know if it's a crime if you aren't  (I'm actually in CR now but trying to conserve mobile data so I'm sorry I can't investigate further).

Comment: It is called a "tip" or a "leak".

Comment: @ohwilleke - this means this information cannot be obtained officially, right?

Comment: @Alexei This means that whether or not it can be obtained officially, that probably isn't how the journalist set about getting the information. If it can be obtained officially it was probably just a "tip", but if it can't be obtained officially, it is a "leak". I have no idea what Costa Rica's laws on that point are.